# Validate first letter case in a string with typescript

Tags: typescript, sass

I am trying to write a function in typescript to validate if the first letter is written in uppercase, but it doesn't work. What is wrong in it ?
Here is my function :

```typescript
    export const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => rule( {
      if(string.charAt(0) !== toUpperCase()){
        return ("please first letter should be uppercase")
      } else {
        return alert("Thanks for being part of it")
       }
    })
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: this function doesnt work, @zerkmas

Comment: "doesnt work" --- this is not a problem description. What does it exactly mean?

Comment: i am trying to capitalize the first letter but this function doesnt work ,how i could make it work? @zerkms

Comment: What does "doesn't work" exactly mean? Elaborating your problem clearly is 50% of being able to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `toUpperCase()` need a string to be chained with like

```
let name = 'ahmad'
name.chatAt(0).toUpperCase()
```

so making an equality check with it is not gonna work.

to achieve the validation check you want you can use simple regular expression

```
export const isFirstLetterInUppercase = (str: string) => {
    if (!(/[A-Z]/.test(str.charAt(0)))) {
        console.log("please first letter should be uppercase");
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log("Thanks for being part of it");
        return true;
    }
}
```